# WordPress & suggest.js - Ajax query receives 200 response but empty content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**CONTEXT**

I am using WordPress' suggest.js feature to create an autosuggest feature on a text field. As you type each character in the field, an Ajax query is sent to the server, which queries an SQL table for a specific variable. The response should be all the variables that correspond to the query.

**CODE**

Here is the code:

```
/DISBLE UPDATE NOTIFICATIONS

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function se_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
}

add_action('wp_head', 'se_wp_head');
function se_wp_head() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#se_search_element_id').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup');
    });
</script>
<?php
}

function se_lookup() {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = like_escape($_REQUEST['q']);

    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta
        WHERE meta_key LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
        ORDER BY post_title ASC';
    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query) as $row) {
        $meta_value = $row->meta_value;



        // echo ' (' . $meta_value . ')' . "\n";

        echo $meta_value;
    }
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
```

**RESULT**

I am getting a 200 response, as if the query is working correctly. However, **response content is empty.** I am expecting `echo $metavalue` to return the variables I am looking for. However, I have tried `echo "test"` instead and that returns empty as well. I've installed a Chrome extension to see the Ajax call/response in Dev Tools and here is what I see within the response:

```
response: Object
_transferSize: 515
bodySize: 33
content: Object
compression: -33
mimeType: "text/html"
size: 0
__proto__: Object
cookies: Array[0]
headers: Array[17]
headersSize: 482
httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"
redirectURL: ""
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
startedDateTime: "2016-02-29T20:34:25.603Z"
time: 385.04700001794845
```

Any ideas why the response content object contains nothing?

Comment: well, you're dumping out your response as a single monolithic string. e.g. if the suggestion results are `egg`, `plant`, and `parmesan`, you're sending over the blob `eggplantparmesan` because there's no separators between each row of query results. you need to mod your script to output data in the same format that the .suggest() plugin is expecting.

Comment: This is actually the next place I blocked - although the answer below gave me the correct Ajax response, I am not seeing a dropdown appear below my form input. Form HTML looks like this: ```<input type="text" id="se_search_element_id" name="fname">```. From other implementations of suggest() in wordpress, I don't think there's a specific format necessary... Any idea what the issue may be here? I created a new question or it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711390/wordpress-suggest-js-ajax-query-returns-correct-response-but-no-dropdown-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting result by **`post_title`** ( i.e `ORDER BY post_title ASC`) but the table `wp_usermeta` doesn't have a column `post_title`.

[image]

Comment: You got it - removing the ```ORDER BY``` yields the correct content.