# WordPress & suggest.js - Ajax query returns correct response but no dropdown appears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**CONTEXT**

In order to implement autocomplete (with dropdown suggestions of possible matches) in WordPress I'm using the following code to get back a series of variables from my SQL table:

```
//DISBLE UPDATE NOTIFICATIONS

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function se_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
}

add_action('wp_head', 'se_wp_head');
function se_wp_head() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#se_search_element_id').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup');
    });
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');

function se_lookup() {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = like_escape($_REQUEST['q']);

    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta
        WHERE meta_key="company" AND meta_value LIKE \'%' . $search . '%\'';

    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query) as $row) {
        $meta_value = $row->meta_value;

        echo $meta_value. "\n";
    }
    die();
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Although this returns the correct values (I'm using a Chrome extension to see results of Ajax call in dev tools), nothing is being displayed below the form field. Form field HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="se_search_element_id" name="fname">
```

I'm not sure if the issue is the format that the Ajax call is returning or whether there is something I'm missing that should make the dropdown appear.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the suggest function should be an array. You are feeding it a url. So, you don't need to use ajax. Just do everything in the head: database query (all companies), json_encode results and echo it into the javascript. If you want to do it by ajax take a look at jQuery autocomplete https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/